# Two functions f(x)=x^x and f(x)=x^(-x)

Tags: coordinate-systems, maxima-minima

I was playing with desmos. Then I found a pair of interesting graphs, namely $f(x)=x^x$(the purple one) and $f(x)=x^{-x}$.(the green one) [image] They both have their global maximum/minimum at a point about $x=0.368$, which I found out is very close to $\frac1e$. Is there some kind of explanation about why this is happening?

You are most welcome to add relevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say $y = x^x$. It would have extrema when $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$.

To differentiate this function, first take $ln()$ on both sides. We get $ln(y) = xln(x)$. Now differentiate w.r.t x.
$\frac{dy/dx}{y} = 1 + ln(x)$. So if $dy/dx = 0$, then $ln(x) = -1$ which means that there is an extrema at $\frac{1}{e}$ whose nature can be determined by the second derivative test.

So it's no surprise that you see a  global maxima/minima at $\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f_1(x)=\frac 1 {f_2(x)}$$ so you should expect that where one achieves its minimum, the other one achieves its maximum.

A closer inspection shows that $$\ln f_1(x)=x\ln x=-f_2(x)$$
and $$\frac{\partial (\ln f_1)}{\partial x}(x)=\ln(x)-1$$
So the minimum/maximum are indeed achieved exactly at $\frac 1 e$.

Answer (score 0):

That minimum of $x^x$  happens at where it’s derivaive is zero. $\frac{dx^x}{dx}=x^x(log(x)+1)=0$ gives $x=1/e$ for positive x.
Similar argument can be made for $x^{-x}$.